# WebMatrix instead of IIS

Tags: iis-7, webmatrix

How can i configure my wcf service in **Web Matrix**? as i am using **Windows 7 home basic**

any help is appreciated!

Comment: WebMatrix is an IDE (which is internally using IIS Express), not a web server. Comparing it to IIS is like comparing apples to oranges.

Comment: Then how can i host my WCF service in IIS, tried so many options to get IIS running in my OS but there is no success :(

Answer (score 0):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/james_osbornes_blog/archive/2010/07/30/webmatrix-iisexpress-beta-hosting-wcf-services.aspx

Check the above link, Hope it helps